# SQL 2012 add data collection russian

Tags: sql-server, unicode, sql-server-2012

I am in the need of a support of Unicode characters where the DB will support Russian as well as English, do I need to add a second collection?

Comment: That I need to add I know, but how I add with a script a second collection, maybe you can tell )))))

Answer (score 0):

Unicode data is stored using the nchar, nvarchar, and ntext data types in SQL Server.

To insert use

For Traditional Method
**Insert into table (textcolumn) values(N'value')**

For Stored Procedures
**Insert into table (textcolumn) Select @parameter**

Comment: Hello, yes I know this that I need to use the nvarchar, however the collection I have now gives the nice looking "?????", so I want to add a second collection and also need to add arabic, which is not to be solved with only the nvarchar format.